# Compute expectation (Ito integral/calculus)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, integration, stochastic-processes

I am having trouble computing this expectation. Does anyone know how to proceed?

$$E\left[e^{2B(t)} \int_0^t s dB(s) \right].$$
Is it 0? I tried expressing $e^{2B(t)}=1+ 2\int_0^t e^{2B(s)}dB(s)+2\int_0^t e^{2B(s)}ds$. Can I say that
$$E\left[e^{2B(t)} \int_0^t s dB(s) \right]= 0+\int_0^tsE[e^{2B(s)}]ds+0.$$
?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to use the fact that $X_t:=\exp(2B_t -2t)$ is a martingale, and in fact is equal to 
$$
1+2\int_0^t X_s dB_s.
$$

Comment: How did you arrive to that? I mean, are you saying that what is inside the expectation equals $1+2\int_0^t X_s dB_s$ ?

Comment: Ok now I understand, I got $t^2 e^{2t}$, I hope it is correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But is it true that $E[\int_0^t X_s dB_s \int_0^t sdB_s] = E\left[\int_0^t sX_s ds\right]$?? even if $X_s$ is depending on $B_s$?

Comment: Yes, it's true, provided the process $X$ is "progressively measurable", and in particular if it's adapted and continuous in time, as is your $X_s$.